# Share resources across power bi projects

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I am dabbling around with the new .pbip extension and the pbi service git extension.

What I could not figure out is how to share resources, such as theme.json, across reports.

So for instance, I have a mono-repo with subfolders, each belonging to a .pbip report.

Does each resource need to be provided in each subfolder? Moreover, how can I properly reference a custom theme.json in a pbip project? If I save as pbip, the theme lands in  RegisteredResources\ but I cannot standardize this across reports?